# How to Create A HashMap using Key Values from a text file?

Tags: java, file, hashmap

I have to create a hashmap with the names I have in this text file

relationships text file:

```js
Susan Sarandon | Tom Hanks : Cloud Atlas
Tom Hanks | Kevin Bacon : Apollo 13
Leonardo Dicaprio | Kevin Bacon : This Boy's Life
Robert De Niro | Kevin Bacon : This Boy's Life
Barack Obama | Tom Hanks : the Road We've Traveled
Helen Keller | Katharine Cornell : Helen Keller in Her Story
Katharine Cornell | Helen Hayes : Stage Door Canteen
Helen Hayes | John Laughlin : Murder with Mirrors
John Laughlin | Kevin Bacon : Footloose
Mark Zuckerberg | Joe Lipari : Terms and Conditions May Apply
Joe Lipari | Welker White : Eat Pray Love
Welker White | Kevin Bacon : Lemon Sky
```

This is the program I have now:

```js
public static void main(String[] args)
 
   throws FileNotFoundException
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("relationships"));
  HashMap<String, String> relationships = new HashMap<String, String>();
  
  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] columns = input.nextLine().split(" ");
            relationships.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
        }

        System.out.println(relationships);
    
  }
```

This is the output:

```js
{Leonardo=Dicaprio, Katharine=Cornell, Joe=Lipari, Tom=Hanks, Robert=De, Susan=Sarandon, John=Laughlin, Mark=Zuckerberg, Barack=Obama, Welker=White, Helen=Hayes}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this please? Also how to seperate them so it actually looks like a list?

Comment: A Map (including all HashMaps) is a one-to-one mapping, but each line of your file contains three data items.  What information do wish each key in your HashMap to contain, and what information should be in each key's corresponding value?  And what does "'looks like a list" mean?

Comment: the name of the actor is the kay and the movie title inlcuding the other actor is the value.

Comment: *key so EX: Susan Sarandon- key, and Tom Hanks : Cloud Atlas- value

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I think you would just change your line:

```
String[] columns = input.nextLine().split(" ");
```

to:

```
String[] columns = input.nextLine().split(Pattern.quote(" | "));
```

Then `column[0]` would be the name on the left, and `column[1]` would be the name and movie title on the right.

Note that you'll need to `import java.util.regex.Pattern;` to do this

Comment: the output didnt change

Comment: Thanks alot man it works! I never heard of regex though... Is that the only way you know how to fix it?

Comment: Yup, you can see standard regex patterns [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: oh.. do you know how I can get the list in order that it has from the text file? I notice it seems to be random

Comment: Use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) from `java.util.LinkedHashMap` instead of a regular HashMap to keep the items in the order they are added.